# Unrecognized getline

Tags: c++, getline

I'm doing a C++ intermediate course on udemy. At the lesson about reading text files the tutor has written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename = "Text.txt";
    ifstream inFile;
    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while (!inFile) {
            getline(inFile, line);
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

On the tutor's computer the program work fine but on my computer I get the error: error C3861: 'getline': identifier not found.
Even worse if I try (as my IDE -Visual Studio 2019- suggested) to replace getline by std::basic_istream::getline I get the error : 'std::basic_istream': use of class template requires template argument list. Does anyone understands what happens?

Comment: `std::getline` is part of the header `<string>` which is not included here.

Comment: you need to include `<string>` to use `getline`. "need" is actually "should" because headers may include other headers, but thats nothing you should rely on

Comment: Adding correct include will solve compiler error, but your program will always print `Unable to open file`, because you never try to open a file.

Comment: you need to get some reference where you can look up such stuff. Nobody can remember every header that is needed for every function from the standard library, but everybody should know how to get that information. Try this one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 1):

add header

```
#include<string>
```

as getline is part of this header file
and I will suggest you to always refer namespace
instead of

```
using namespace std;
```

use

```
std::cout
std::getline 
etc
```